# How to multiple color object detection using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I am attempting to detect the position of some colored objects to send it to a robot. the objects are colored notebooks like this:

[image: like this]

My approach was to do separate thresholding to find the red, green and blue separately and then applying `Canny` filter for each one then `findcontours` for every color independently of the other colors.
i feel this way of thinking is bad and has low efficiency, So any help would be greatly appreciated.

the code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    Mat src,gthreshold,rthreshold,bthreshold,hsv;
    Mat ggray, rgray, bgray,gray;

    namedWindow("src", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("gthreshol", 1);
    namedWindow("rthreshol", 1);
    namedWindow("bthreshol", 1);
    namedWindow("ggray", 1);
    namedWindow("rgray", 1);
    namedWindow("bgray", 1);

    cout << "windows created" << endl;

    vector<vector<Point>>gcontours;
    vector<vector<Point>>rcontours;
    vector<vector<Point>>bcontours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    while (true)
    {

        cap.read(src);

        if (!cap.isOpened())
        {cout << "not opened camera" << endl;}


        cvtColor(src, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);   // converts the RGB image to HSV 
        inRange(hsv, Scalar(32, 51, 34), Scalar(100, 250, 138), gthreshold); // finds out the green objects 
        inRange(hsv, Scalar(148, 49, 0), Scalar(179, 255, 205), rthreshold);
        inRange(hsv, Scalar(93, 53, 0), Scalar(157, 255, 123), bthreshold);

        erode(gthreshold, gthreshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));    // noise reduction 
        dilate(gthreshold, gthreshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        dilate(gthreshold, gthreshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        erode(gthreshold, gthreshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        blur(gthreshold, gthreshold, Size(3, 3));

        erode(rthreshold, rthreshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));    // noise reduction 
        dilate(rthreshold, rthreshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        dilate(rthreshold, rthreshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        erode(rthreshold, rthreshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        blur(rthreshold, rthreshold, Size(3, 3));

        erode(bthreshold, bthreshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));    // noise reduction 
        dilate(bthreshold, bthreshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        dilate(bthreshold, bthreshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        erode(bthreshold, bthreshold, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        blur(bthreshold, bthreshold, Size(3, 3));

        imshow("gthreshol", gthreshold);
        imshow("rthreshol", rthreshold);
        imshow("bthreshol", bthreshold);

        Canny(gthreshold, ggray, 20, 255, 3);
        Canny(rthreshold, rgray, 20, 255, 3);
        Canny(bthreshold, bgray, 20, 255, 3);

        imshow("ggray", ggray);
        imshow("rgray", rgray);
        imshow("bgray", bgray);

        findContours(ggray, gcontours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        findContours(rgray, rcontours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        findContours(bgray, bcontours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


        for (int i = 0; i < gcontours.size(); i++)
        {
            int area = contourArea(gcontours[i], false);
            if (area > 1000)
            {
                cout << "green area = " << area << endl; break;
            }


                cout << "green" << endl;


        }

        for (int k = 0; k < rcontours.size(); k++)
        {
            int rarea = contourArea(gcontours[k], false);

            if (rarea > 1000) {
                cout << "red area = " << rarea << endl; break;
            }


        }

        for (int n = 0; n < rcontours.size(); n++)
        {
            int barea = contourArea(gcontours[n], false);

            if (barea > 100) {
                cout << "blue area = " << barea << endl; break;
            }


        }


        imshow("src", src);


        if (waitKey(30) == 27)
        {
            cout << "esc is pressed" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "the end :) " << endl;
    return(0);

}
```

Comment: Why don't you write a function instead of copy-pasting the same code over and over?

Comment: Your approach sounds completely normal. If you want the notebooks separated and they overlap, you will have to create a binary image for each notebook. Shouldn't really be that inefficient.

Comment: @DanMašek I'm completely new to c++ and openCv, I'm in the department of electric power but i need this code as a task in the project. so i will try to use functions. Thanks for your advice:) .

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds my problem is how to draw the contours for each notebook depending on which one is appeared in front of the camera. i.e. red rectangle for red notebook .... etc

Comment: @Amr Understood, do try that. It should help make the algorithm easier to understand, and it will be easier to fix bugs (since you have to fix them in one place instead of 3 in your case). | At this stage I wouldn't worry about efficiency -- first find a working algorithm, then worry about optimizing it if necessary. Since the objects are red, green and blue, analyzing the individual planes of a BGR image seems sensible.

Comment: The notebooks look transparent. In your position, I'd first enumerate all the possible scenarios -- nothing, 1 notebook, 2 notebooks (separate, overlap), 3 notebooks (separate, 2 overlap, 3 overlap). Can they fully overlap? That would add some more scenarios. Then think about how to deal with each of those scenarios.

Comment: @DanMašek i could do some thing like this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bexNpsb90As) using moments instead of findcontours, it works well but i need to draw the rectangular fram around every object and get angle,length...etc. like this guy [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQ-bpfdWQh8)